# Подсчет количества записей с условием

Tags: yii2

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать запрос с условием, чтобы подсчет записей велся по полю status, только когда у этого поля значение 0. Запрос я написал таким образом, но подсчет идет всех записей и со статусом 0 и 1.

```
$count_contact = ContactForm::find()->where('status' == 0)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count_contact = ContactForm::find()->where(['status' => 0])->count();
```

или

```
$count_contact = ContactForm::find()->where('status = 0')->count();
```